# Can not change country of apple ID

Tags: iphone

It doesn't work when I change the country of my apple ID. I come to the page where I need to fill in my address and billing information, but when I press next I come back to settings and when I press view apple ID, the country has not changed.

What can I do?

Comment: from which tool are you trying this, I mean safari or itunes, mac or windows, iOS device or what?

Comment: If this is the case, why does it state "To change the country or region associated with this account" etc when you select the current country? There must be a way to change it, but I only seem to get as far as Erika? Have you got any further? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Changing the country for an Apple ID is impossible. Unfortunately it has never been. It is most probably related to the fact that you are not expected to simply hop from one country to the next and change your payment information associated with your Apple ID (i.e. local credit card) with it.

However, it is possible to open multiple Apple Accounts each associated with a different country and if needed a credit-card issued in the respective country.

Comment: instead of a credit card issued in that country you can use a gift card from that country.